Grub2Win is not able to boot Ubuntu 22.04
I´m new to Ubuntu and lately tried to do a dual install on an old desktop. Here the details:
Old WinXP Desktop (used only for some lovely old games, not connected to the internet, so don´t panic! ;-)) with

1 internal disk for WinXP installation, drive C & G (emergency XP partition)
1 internal SSD data disk, drive D
1 internal 1 TB disk, where I installed Ubuntu from bootable USB image for some Linux testing etc.

Win boot manager starts from drive C with entries for WinXP (C:) and emergency XP (G:). In addition I´ve installed Grub2Win on drive C and maintained the Grub boot entries. So now Windows boot manager has entry for Grub2Win and when I chose this Grub2Win starts. Unfortunately when I now chose to boot the Ubuntu 22.04 installation on the 1 TB disk I get an error message:
Error: no such device: bea8c76e-... .
*** Grub did not find a root partition with uuid bea8c76e-...
*** Press the ESC key to continue
Although this is the correct uuid which is even shown, when I check all disks with Grub2.
With WinXP I´m not able to access the 1 TB drive but when I boot Ubuntu from a pen drive I´m able to see the drive and the partitions on it with all the needed uuids:
/dev/sdf1  EFI
/dev/sdf2  (should be data partition)
/dev/sdf3  Ubuntu installation
... btw I´m even able to mount the partition and access the folders/paths.
But still after several tries, I´m not able to get sdf3 (Ubuntu installation) booted.
Any help is very much apreciated ... or maybe I did overlook some details?
Grub2Win Rel. 2.1.3.3 (offline install because the WinXP desktop is not connected to the internet)
Ubuntu Rel. 22.04
